# Problems Using Ucanaccess with msaccess

Tags: java

I am using the IDE Nebeans8.1 and data base access 2019. 
I got an error while trying to connect to my datavse using ucanaccess and all needed libraries.

My `ConnectionDatabase` class:

```java
package hospital;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 ** @author MicroSoft**
 */
public class ConnectionDatabase {

    static Connection con = null;

    public static Connection connet(){

        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//MicroSoft//Documents//NetBeansProjects//hospital//hospital.accdb"); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " pass ");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        con = connet();
    }
}
```

the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

[image: problem msg]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong version of the commons-lang dependency.

You need a version of commons-lang 3, but you are using commons-lang 2.6.  Try replacing this with a version of commons-lang 3.